# how to increase spacing between rows in tinter listbox - python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter listbox initialised as follows:

```
self.serives_listbox = tk.Listbox(parent, font=("TkTextFont", 20), exportselection=False, width=30, height = 15)
self.serives_listbox.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=5, pady=10)
```

I then add items to the listbox like this:

```
for key, value in service_list[str(self.category_combox.get())].items():
    self.serives_listbox.insert(tk.END, str(key))
```

I need a way to increase the spacing between the rows of the lisbox

Thank you

Comment: You could add blank rows?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change the spacing between items in a tkinter listbox, other than to insert blank items.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert some empty elements on odd or even positions,
then you should bind a function to clear your empty selection

```py
def clearselect(event):
    var=event.widget.curselection()[0]
    if var%2 != 0: #for odd empty items
        #you can check here for even or odd
        #like for even empty elements var%2==0
        event.widget.select_clear(var)
        event.widget.select_set(var-1)
        #for even empty items 'var+1'

lstBox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',clearselect)
```