# Giving spaces to tkinter listbox items

Tags: tkinter

I created a listbox with Tkinter. I want to put a space between the items in this listbox.

How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to increase spacing between rows in tinter listbox - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221755/how-to-increase-spacing-between-rows-in-tinter-listbox-python)

Comment: You can't add spacing between items inside a `tk.Listbox`. You can create your own listbox widget using a bunch of `tk.Entry`s or `tk.Label`s.

Comment: No @TheLizzard :(

Comment: You can try setting the `selectborderwidth` option but it will change the outlook of the selection bar as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I made a class that is similar to `Listbox` but allows to specify the vertical spacing between items:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label


class SpacedListbox(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, ipady=0):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.config(relief='sunken', bd=2)
        self.__item_list = []
        self.ipady = ipady

    def __refresh_items(self):
        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

        for item in self.__item_list:
            label = Label(self, text=item, anchor='w')
            label.pack(ipady=self.ipady, fill='x')

    def insert(self, index, *elements):
        last = len(self.__item_list) - 1
        if index == 'end':
            index = last
        elif index >= len(self.__item_list):
            index = last
        temp_lst = []
        if index != last:
            temp_lst = self.__item_list[index:]
            self.__item_list = self.__item_list[:index]
        for item in elements:
            self.__item_list.append(item)
        self.__item_list += temp_lst
        self.__refresh_items()


root = Tk()

lstbox = SpacedListbox(root, 10)
lstbox.pack(fill='x', padx=10, pady=10)

lstbox.insert('end', 'Hello', 'World', 'Time', 'Song')

root.mainloop()
```

The `insert` method works but it is kinda messy I would say. Otherwise it should function the same as the `Listbox().insert()` so there is that. Obviously on other functionality has been added nor there are any more options yet, but at least that is the start, so feel free to use this `SpacedListbox` class as You need.

The one adjustment that could be added is using canvas below frame so that it can be scrolled and doesn't expand out of the screen. Other stuff like selecting items could also be added. But the basics are there at least and You can work with these.